# Excel VBA to find the last row on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to paste data into a worksheet below the data. I've got the following:

```
Set BaseWks = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Total Data")
    rnum = BaseWks.Worksheets("Total Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

But it gives me an error: `method or data member not found`. What am I doing worng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need

```
rnum = BaseWks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
```

as you have already defined `BaseWks` as that sheet.

You also need `.row` on the end to return the row number.

If you want the cell itself you need `Set rnum= ...` instead.